# Symfony2 Assetic - path to image from inside a CSS-File

Tags: css, image, assetic, symfony-2.8

I have a problem to get the right path from a pic inside a css-file (background-image)

The pic is inside

```
src / AppBundle / Resources / public / pics / blau.png
```

The css-file inside

```
src / AppBundle / Resources / public / css / default0.css
```

I have a  in the index.html.twig (app / Resources / views / default) 
witch should get the background-image blau.png.

In the css I can format the div with border and size, no problem, but the backgound-image is not visible:

I've try the following syntax:

```
background-image: url("pics/blau.png") ;
background-image: url("../pics/blau.png") ;
background-image: url("../../pics/blau.png") ;
```

I can't find the Problem.
THX

---

I installed assetic :

```
php app/console assets:install
```

and run

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

and what I also installed and config are Assetic

```
$ composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

First put your images in the folder : (Manually or by assetic)

> Web/uploads/public/pics

and in your css-file :

```
background-image: url({{ asset('uploads/public/pics/blau.gif') }});
```